# Case statement resolved with ERROR - FROM keyword not found where expected

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I try to execute a query and on the fly to create a new column which its value depends on other columns using case statements. Note that RATE is a new column that does not exist in the table. can you please tell me where am i wrong?

```
SELECT PAY_ATTR1.ID,
       PAY_ATTR1.AMOUNT,
       PAY_ATTR1.TAX,
       ISSYNC = CASE WHEN PAY_ATTR1.AMOUNT != PAY_ATTR2.AMOUNT THEN 'DIFF' ELSE NULL END 
FROM PAY_ATTR1
    INNER JOIN PAY_ATTR2
    ON PAY_ATTR1.ID=PAY_ATTR2.ID
```

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: `Alias = <expression>` is syntax specific to SQL Server, in Oracle you will need to use the standard `<expression> AS Alias` syntax for giving a column an alias.

Comment: I found that, after 'End', I have to use `AS "Alias"`, here the Alias has to use <b>double quote<b/>, otherwise it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PAY_ATTR1.ID,
       PAY_ATTR1.AMOUNT,
       PAY_ATTR1.TAX,
       CASE WHEN PAY_ATTR1.AMOUNT != PAY_ATTR2.AMOUNT THEN 'DIFF' END as ISSYNC  
FROM PAY_ATTR1
    INNER JOIN PAY_ATTR2
    ON PAY_ATTR1.ID=PAY_ATTR2.ID
```

Comment: yes, i thought about this solution the problem is that i want to use the field ISSYNC also on other cases and if i do this CASE WHEN PAY_ATTR1.AMOUNT != PAY_ATTR2.AMOUNT THEN 'DIFF' END as ISSYNC  
and after i add additional case like CASE WHEN PAY_ATTR1.TAX != PAY_ATTR2.TAX THEN 'DIFF' END as ISSYNC    in this case it will add another colums as ISSYNC_1 but i want to use the same field.

Comment: If you want it to be in the same column, just add more expressions, e.g. `CASE WHEN PAY_ATTR1.AMOUNT != PAY_ATTR2.AMOUNT THEN 'DIFF' WHEN PAY_ATTR1.TAX != PAY_ATTR2.TAX THEN 'DIFF'  END AS ISSYNC`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PAY_ATTR1.ID,
       PAY_ATTR1.AMOUNT,
       PAY_ATTR1.TAX,
       CASE WHEN PAY_ATTR1.AMOUNT != PAY_ATTR2.AMOUNT THEN 'DIFF' 
            ELSE NULL 
            END AS ISSYNC
FROM PAY_ATTR1 INNER JOIN PAY_ATTR2 
    ON PAY_ATTR1.ID = PAY_ATTR2.ID
```

Comment: `[ISSYNC]` is an invalid identifier in (standard) SQL and Oracle